# Django Http404 and DEBUG mode catch 22

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404

I'm using the `staticfiles` app during development, which doesn't work unless DEBUG is turned on.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development):

> Warning This will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That's because this view is grossly inefficient and probably insecure.
>   This is only intended for local development, and should never be used
>   in production.
>
> Additionally, when using staticfiles_urlpatterns your STATIC_URL
>   setting can't be empty or a full URL, such as
>   http://static.example.com/.

I'm trying to view my Http404 templates, though, and of course they **don't** work in DEBUG mode. So I'm in a catch 22 - if I want to view the 404 page I have to turn off DEBUG, but then no static files are servers and I can't see any images, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply pretend you are in production. Run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

To have all your files copied to `STATIC_ROOT`. Then, temporarily add the following to urls.py:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
)
```

You'll have to run `collectstatic` each time you make a change to any static files, so I would suggest live-editing in something like Firebug and then saving the finished product. Also, remember to delete the `static` directory and remove that line from urls.py when you're done.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tried it myself, but you might try setting DEBUG_PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/